# error message in oledbcommand.executenonquery();

Tags: c#, database, debugging, ms-access-2010

I wrote the following program in C#
I have no problem when inserting information in the database
But when deleting information and during debugging, it gets an error on the following
line
cmd.executenonquery();

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace _01_AccessTestDB
{
public partial class frmUser : Form
{
    public frmUser()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data 
    Source=TestDB.accdb");
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    
    void display()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        adp.SelectCommand=new OleDbCommand();
        adp.SelectCommand.Connection= con;
        adp.SelectCommand.CommandText="select * from TBLUser";
        adp.Fill(ds, "TBLUser");
        dgvUser.DataSource=ds;
        dgvUser.DataMember=("TBLUser");

        dgvUser.Columns[0].HeaderText="کد";
        dgvUser.Columns[1].HeaderText="نام کاربری";
        dgvUser.Columns[2].HeaderText="کلمه عبور";
    }

    
    

    private void frmUser_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        display();
       
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandText="insert into TBLUser(ID,UserN,Pass)values(@a,@b,@c)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", txtCode.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", txtUser.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", txtPass.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        string message, title;
        title="تعریف کاربران";
        message="اطلاعات جدید با موفقیت ثبت گردید";
        MessageBox.Show(message, title, MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
        MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        txtCode.Clear();
        txtUser.Clear();
        txtPass.Clear();
        display();
    }
```

The program is running correctly so far, but it encountered a problem in the data deletion section

```
    private void btnDelet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       
    {
        int h = Convert.ToInt32(dgvUser.SelectedCells[0].Value);
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.Connection=con;
        cmd.CommandText="delet from TBLUser Where ID=@N";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@N", h);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        string message, title;
        title="تعریف کاربران";
        message="اطلاعات حذف گردید";
        MessageBox.Show(message, title, MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
        MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        display();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: Funny, the first words of the title are "error message" yet there's no error message anywhere in the question.

Comment: You are doing things very much the wrong way. Create a `DataTable` - not a `DataSet` and populate that, bind it to a `BindingSource` and bind that to the grid. To delete a record, call `RemoveCurrent` on the `BindingSource`. All changes you make, including deletes, affect only that local `DataTable`. so save the changes, call `Update` on your data adapter and pass the `DataTable`. You will need to configure the data adpter appropriately, with `InsertCommand` and/or `UpdateCommand` and/or `DeleteCommand`.

Answer (score 0):

Change from

`cmd.CommandText="delet from TBLUser Where ID=@N";`

To

`cmd.CommandText="delete from TBLUser Where ID=@N";`

Also follow @user18387401 recommendations

In regards to `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue`, use `cmd.Parameters.Add` instead.

**Edit**

Here is a model to use for removing a record use SQL-Server in .NET Core. Since you are using Access the connection and command change to OleDb. So don't copy-n-paste this code, adapt to your current code. The `Remove` method should reside in a separate class but can reside in the form.

Best to add in a BindingSource, this way cast someBindingSource.Current to whatever the current row in the DataGridView is e.g. if the source is a DataTable use ((DataRow)someBindingSource.Current).Row.Field... to get the primary key to use for deleting. Once the record is removed use someBindingSource.RemoveCurrent() to remove the record from your DataGridView.

```
public static (bool success, Exception exception) Remove(int identifier)
{
    using var cn = new SqlConnection("TODO");
    using var cmd = new SqlCommand
    {
        Connection = cn,
        CommandText = "DELETE FROM TBLUser WHERE Id = @Identifier;"
    };

    try
    {
        cn.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Identifier", SqlDbType.Int).Value = identifier;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return (true, null);
    }
    catch (Exception localException)
    {
        return (false, localException);
    }

}
```

Usage in your form (`DataOperations` is a separate class)

```
var (success, exception) = DataOperations.Remove(identifier);
if (success)
{
    // record removed
}
else
{
    // deal with exception using exception variable
}
```

Comment: By changing the delet to delete, the problem of not being executed was solved, but now it gives the message to delete, but it is not deleted   -------   tanks @Karen Payne

Comment: See the edit in my reply. You can't drop the code in directly but follow the logic and see if an exception is thrown, if so edit your question and post the message from the thrown exception.